# Connect Amazon DocumentDB without using EC2

Tags: aws-documentdb

How do I connect to AWS DocumentDB without EC2? I do not have .PEM file to connect with EC2.

I downloaded Studio 3T and tried to establish the connection. It requires SSH .pem file setup in connection. I do not have .PEM file so looking for other options.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the AWS Global Cert Bundle here: https://truststore.pki.rds.amazonaws.com/global/global-bundle.pem

Trying to connect to an Amazon DocumentDB cluster directly from a public endpoint, such as your laptop or local development machine, will fail. Amazon DocumentDB is virtual private cloud (VPC)-only and does not currently support public endpoints. Thus, you can't connect directly to your Amazon DocumentDB cluster from your laptop or local development environment outside of your VPC.

To connect to an Amazon DocumentDB cluster from outside an Amazon VPC, you can use an SSH tunnel. For more information, see Connecting to an Amazon DocumentDB Cluster from Outside an Amazon VPC. Additionally, if your development environment is in a different Amazon VPC, you can also use VPC Peering and connect to your Amazon DocumentDB cluster from another Amazon VPC in the same region or a different region.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/troubleshooting.connecting.html#troubleshooting.cannot-connect.public-endpoints